# Maven - When to use parent/child relation versus just adding a dependency

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

I am very new to Maven (or for that matter the whole CICD thing) so please forgive me for this theoretical question without providing any examples.

I just want to understand the difference between adding another project/artifact as a **dependency** to my project vs adding it as a **parent**. I mean, if I just include the required project/artifact as a dependency then that will also bring in the transitive dependencies as well, right? Especially, now that we have `import` scope available to us, this question totally baffles me.

Why do I need the parent/child relationship in POM after all?

Any examples or explanation would be a great help.

Comment: Guys, i guess there is a diff related to `<dependencyManagement>` section but I am hoping for something more than that here.

Comment: adding a dependency will just affect the transitive dependency resolution.  However, you are inheriting more than dependencies from parent.  For example, the plugins to use, `dependencyManagement` to use, build settings, repositories, etc